# Double integral using polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We are asked to evaluate the double integral: $\iint_U xy\,dx\,dy$ where $U$ is the region where $x^2+2x+y^2-6y$ is less than equal to six. I am not able to understand what the limits of $\theta$ and $r$ are going to be and how to go about finding them. When I draw the circle in the $xy$ plane it fits into all 4 quadrants so is $\theta$ ranging from $0$ to $2\pi$? But I have no idea how to find  the limits of $r$.

Comment: I still don't understand, I have used the substitutions: u=x+1 and v=y-3  and still not arrived at the right answer.

Comment: is answer  $-24\pi$?

Comment: To be honest I don't know the right answer but I got -48pi, but it doesn't seem right.

Comment: The region (a circle) is mostly in the second quadrant, where $ \ xy < 0 \ , $ so a negative value for the integral is reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably easiest to do a substitution such that your region of integration is translated over to a circle centered at the origin.  Then your theta would be going from $0$ to $2\pi$ while your $r$ would be going from $0$ to the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate what has been suggested both by **user134711** and **mathematician**, we'll do the integration all three ways, as each has its own complications and (related) economies.

[image]

The region $ \ U \ $ is the circle $ \ (x+1)^2 \ + \ (y-3)^2 \ = \ 16 , $ centered at $ \ (-1, 3) \ $ with radius 4.  (This already suggests the sort of substitutions we will wish to make.)

If we just choose to carry out the integral as presented, and decide to integrate with respect to $ \ y \ $ first, we will want to write the equation of the circle as a pair of (semicircle) functions of the form $ \ y(x) \ $, given by

$$   (y-3)^2 \ = \ 16 \ - \ (x+1)^2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ = \ 3 \ \pm \ \sqrt{16 \ - \ (x+1)^2} \ \ . $$

We can work out analytically, or just see by the graph, that the integration in $ \ x \ $ should run over the interval $ \ [-5, 3] \ . $  Our integral is then

$$ \iint_U \ xy \ \ dy \ dx \ \ = \ \ \int_{-5}^3 \ \int_{ \ 3 \ - \ \sqrt{16 \ - \ (x+1)^2}}^{ \ 3 \ + \ \sqrt{16 \ - \ (x+1)^2}} \ xy \ \ dy \ dx  $$

(as horrible as this may look at the moment, we'll find there is a lot of cancelation ahead)

$$ = \ \ \int_{-5}^3 \  \left( \ \frac{1}{2}xy^2 \ \right) \vert_{ \ 3 \ - \ \sqrt{16 \ - \ (x+1)^2}}^{ \ 3 \ + \ \sqrt{16 \ - \ (x+1)^2}}  \ \ dx $$

$$ = \ \ \frac{1}{2} \ \int_{-5}^3 \  x \ [ \  ( \ 9 \ + \ 6 \ \sqrt{16 \ - \ (x+1)^2} \ + \ [16 \ - \ (x+1)^2] \ ) $$
$$ - \ ( \ 9 \ - \ 6 \ \sqrt{16 \ - \ (x+1)^2} \ + \ [16 \ - \ (x+1)^2] \ ) \ ] \ \ dx $$

$$ = \ \ \frac{1}{2} \ \int_{-5}^3 \  x \ (  \ 12 \ \sqrt{16 \ - \ (x+1)^2}  ) \ \ dx \ \ = \ 6 \ \int_{-5}^3 \  x \  \sqrt{16 \ - \ (x+1)^2}   \ \ dx  \ \ . $$

(we now make the $ \ u-$ substitution (which the equation for the circle suggests), $ \ u = x + 1 \ , \ x = u - 1 \ , \ dx = du \ $ )

$$ \rightarrow \ \ 6 \ \int_{-4}^4 \  (u - 1) \  \sqrt{16 \ - \ u^2}   \ \ du  \ \ = \ \ 6 \ \left[ \ \int_{-4}^4 \  u \  \sqrt{16 \ - \ u^2}   \ \ du \  -  \ \int_{-4}^4 \   \sqrt{16 \ - \ u^2}   \ \ du \  \right]  \ \ . $$

Here we can save ourselves a lot of travail if we recognize a couple things.  The integrand in the first integral is an odd function of $ \ x \ $ (over its domain) and is being integrated over an interval symmetric about the $ \ y-$ axis.  Thus, this integral is just *zero*.  We can carry out the second integral using a "sine substitution", or we can notice that the integrand function describes a semi-circle of radius 4 above the $ \ x-$ axis.  This is then an area integral with a value of $ \ \frac{1}{2} \cdot \pi \cdot 4^2 \ = \ 8 \pi \ $ ; thus,

$$    -6  \ \int_{-4}^4 \   \sqrt{16 \ - \ u^2}   \ \ du \ \ = \  -48 \pi \ \ .  $$

$$ \ \ $$

If we make the change of coordinates axes mentioned by **mathematician**, but stay in rectangular coordinates (which uses the axes in red in the graph above), then we apply the $ \ u-$ substitution as before, as well as the substitution  $ \ v = y - 3 \ , \ y = v +  3 \ , \ dy = dv \ . $  [As we would expect, a simple translation of the circle does not change its area, as the Jacobian for this transformation is just $ \ \left|\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right| \ . $ ]  Our integral becomes

$$  \int_{-4}^4 \ \int_{ \ - \sqrt{16 \ - \ u^2}}^{ \  \sqrt{16 \ - \ u^2}} \ (u - 1) \ (v + 3) \ \ dv \ du  $$

$$ = \ \ \int_{-4}^4 \ (u - 1) \ \left( \ \frac{1}{2} v^2 \ + \ 3v \ \right) \vert_{ \  - \ \sqrt{16 \ - \ u^2}}^{ \  \sqrt{16 \ - \ u^2}} \ \ du $$

$$ = \ \ \int_{-4}^4 \ (u - 1) \ ( \ [  \ \frac{1}{2} \cdot (16 \ - \ u^2) \ + \ 3 \cdot \sqrt{16 \ - \ u^2} \ ]   $$
$$ - \ [  \ \frac{1}{2} \cdot (16 \ - \ u^2) \ - \ 3 \cdot \sqrt{16 \ - \ u^2} \ ] \ )  $$

$$ = 6 \ \int_{-4}^4 \  (u - 1) \  \sqrt{16 \ - \ u^2}   \ \ du \ \ , $$

arriving at the same integral we found above.

Since there was a discrepant factor of 2 among the results in the comments, we can develop a general formula as a check.  For a circle of radius $ \ R \  $ centered at $ \ (x_0, y_0) \ , $ we would have the integral

$$  \int_{-R}^R \ \int_{ \ - \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ u^2}}^{ \  \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ u^2}} \ (u + x_0) \ (v + y_0) \ \ dv \ du  $$

$$ = \ \ \int_{-R}^R \ \ (u + x_0) \ \cdot \  2 y_0 \ \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ u^2} \ \  du \ \ = \ \ 2 y_0 \ \int_{-R}^R \ \ x_0 \    \sqrt{R^2 \ - \ u^2} \ \  du $$

$$ = \ \ 2 x_0 y_0 \ \cdot \ \frac{1}{2} \pi \ R^2 \ = \   \pi \ x_0 y_0 \ R^2 \ \ .  \ \ \ \mathbf{ [1] } $$

[**EDIT:**  This can be thought of as the product of the area of the circle and the area of the rectangle bounded by the $ \ xy-$ axes and the $ \ uv-$ axes, with appropriate choice of sign.]

Hence, for this circle, $ \iint_U \ xy \ \ dy \ dx \ \ = \ \pi \cdot (-1) \cdot 3  \cdot 4^2 \ = \ -48 \pi \ \ . $

$$ \ \ $$

To make this integration in polar coordinates, we again follow **mathematician**'s proposal, starting with the translated circle:

$$  \int_{-4}^4 \ \int_{ \ - \sqrt{16 \ - \ u^2}}^{ \  \sqrt{16 \ - \ u^2}} \ (u - 1) \ (v + 3) \ \ dv \ du \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \int^{2 \pi}_0  \int_0^4 \ (r \cos \theta - 1) \ (r \sin \theta + 3) \ \ r dr \ d\theta $$

$$ = \ \ \int^{2 \pi}_0  \int_0^4 \ ( \ r^3 \cos \theta  \sin \theta \ + \ 3r^2 \cos \theta \ - \ r^2 \sin \theta \ - \ 3r \ ) \ \  dr \ d\theta  $$

$$ = \ \ \int^{2 \pi}_0  \ \left(  \frac{1}{4}r^4 \cdot \frac{1}{2}  \sin 2 \theta \ + \ r^3 \cos \theta \ - \ \frac{1}{3}r^3 \sin \theta \ - \ \frac{3}{2}r^2 \ \right) {\LARGE\vert}_0^4 \   d\theta  $$

$$ = \ \ \int^{2 \pi}_0  \ 32 \  \sin 2 \theta \ + \ 64 \ \cos \theta \ - \ \frac{64}{3} \ \sin \theta \ - \ 24  \ \   d\theta \ \ . $$

Now, the first term is a sine function being integrated over two full periods, and the next two terms are sine and cosine functions integrated over one full period.  So these contribute *zero* to the integral, which thus reduces to

$$ \int^{2 \pi}_0    - \ 24  \ \   d\theta \ \  = \ -24 \ \cdot \ 2 \pi \ = \ -48 \pi \ \ . $$

We also see that this polar integral can be easily generalized to produce the formula $ \ \mathbf{1} \ $ we derived above.

Comment: +1. But I fail to see "complications" in the last approach.

Comment: Well, for the polar integral, the extent of the "complication" is that you actually have to multiply out the two binomials. (I know, the agony...)

Comment: Indeed, I am nearly dead... :-) Seriously this is the best one, by far.

Comment: Note that integrating first with respect to theta (instead of r) shortens the proof even more since this cancels every term except (-3r).

Comment: True enough!  I suppose I'd have taken that route if the integration in $ \ r \ $ had been particularly onerous.